# Plot arrow outside of figure instead of inside

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate, geom-segment

I am trying to plot the arrow outside of the figure. I have tried a number of different options, but they keep plotting the arrow inside the figure. Is there a way to plot it outside the bounding box?

```
set.seed(57)
discharge <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2011-12-31"), by="days"),
discharge = rexp(365))

test <- ggplot(discharge) +
geom_line(aes(x = date, y = discharge)) +
geom_hline(yintercept = 5.5, linetype= "dashed", color = "red") + 
geom_text(aes(x = date[13], y = 5.5, label = "High"))

(test + annotate(geom = "segment", x = as.Date("2011-01-01"), 
              y = -1, xend = as.Date("2011-01-01"), yend = 0, 
              arrow = arrow(length = unit(3, "mm")), color = "red"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the nice features introduced with `ggplot2 >= 3.5.0` (!!!) is that it is now possible to place annotations as numbers in relative units of the plot panel (see [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2024/02/ggplot2-3-5-0/#ignoring-scales)). To this end we have to wrap the positions inside `annotate` in `I()`. Doing so has the advantage that adding an annotation does not affect the range of the scale.

Additionally, as usual we have to set `clip="off"` in `coord_cartesian` and make some room outside of the plot panel e.g. via `plot.margin`.

```r
set.seed(57)
discharge <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2011-12-31"), by = "days"),
  discharge = rexp(365)
)

library(ggplot2)

packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.5.0'

test <- ggplot(discharge) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = discharge)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 5.5, linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
  geom_text(data = ~.x[13, , drop = FALSE], aes(x = date, y = 5.5, label = "High"))

test + 
  annotate(
    geom = "segment", x = as.Date("2011-01-01"),
    y = I(-.125), xend = as.Date("2011-01-01"), yend = I(-.05),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(3, "mm")), color = "red"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 22, 5.5))
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this without ```coord_cartesian(clip = "off")```? when I use this for my actual data, I create a gap between the bounding box and the figure. im wondering if this is because in my plot code, I have ```coord_cartesian(expand = 0)```

Comment: Try `coord_cartesian(clip = "off", expand = 0)`. (;

Comment: thank you! ive had to also add xlim and ylim ranges that were just slightly wider than the data and it got everything correct! :)